# unable to find the correct exception

Tags: python, neo4j, exception, py2neo

I use py2neo to insert data from a json. Everything works perfects.

But I was unable to find in the documentation the information related to this exception.

```
neo4j.exceptions.ConstraintError: Node(0) already exists with label `Documents` and property `itemid` = '994263771'
```

I was trying with

```
except py2neo.database.status.ConstraintError
```

But this only work with py2neo 3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently have a [uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/cypher-intro/schema/#cypher-intro-schema-constraints) on the `itemid` property of the `Documents` label. Therefore, whenever neo4j detects that you are trying to create a new `Documents` node with the same `itemid` value as an existing `Documents` node, it is throwing an exception indicating a constraint violation.

You should use the `merge` method instead of `create`.

Comment: thanks for the response. But I am looking for the exception to catch that! the code is just for explanation purpose. 

Because I have to do something if the element already exists in neo4j.

Comment: You should be avoiding the exception by using `merge`. That is the best practice. Catching the exception would cause terrible performance.